# Is there a way to get the mean value of previous two columns in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nan

I want to calculate the mean value of previous two rows and fill the NAN's in my dataframe. There are only few rows with missing values in the `2010-19` column.

I tried using `bfill` and `ffill` but it only captures the previous or next row/column value and fill NAN.

My example data set has 7 columns as below:

```
X       1990-2000   2000-2010   2010-19   1990-2000  2000-2010   2010-19
Hyderabad    10          20       NAN         1         3           NAN
```

The output I want:

```
X          1990-2000   2000-2010   2010-19   1990-2000  2000-2010   2010-19
Hyderabad    10          20          15         1           3         2
```

Comment: Could you please clarify how do you want to fill `NaN` values?

Comment: I fixed your formatting.

Comment: The question can't be answered until you tell us what you want to fill the NaNs with... what values? Zero? Last non-NaN value (forward-fill?) Next non-NaN value (backward-fill)? Column mean? Something else? Where did the `15` and `2` come from in your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) row-wise in this way, an easy solution is to provide an pandas series as argument to `fillna`. This will replace `NaN` values depending on the index.

Since the column names have duplicates the below code uses the column indices. Assuming a dataframe called `df`:

```
col_indices = [3, 6]

for i in col_indices:
    means = df.iloc[:, [i-1, i-2]].mean(axis=1)
    df.iloc[:, i].fillna(means, inplace=True)
```

This will fill the `NaN` values with the mean of the two columns to the left of each column in `col_indices`.